# Groovy test case with string array iteration

Tags: arrays, groovy

I have a test case where i need to test multiple strings and they are initialised as String[]

```
   myArray.each {
        shouldFail(IllegalArgumentException) {
            println "it = " + it
            testObj.testMyString("$prefix $it", mockBuilder);
         }
    }
```

the print statement shows that `"it"` is null. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name your each var, it should work:

```
myArray.each { element ->
    shouldFail(IllegalArgumentException) {
        println "it = $element"
        testObj.testMyString("$prefix $element", mockBuilder)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each closure has its own "it". In your case when "it" was null, it was `shouldFail` closure's "it" and not `myArray.each`'s closure.

Answer (score 0):

it worked when I changed the code to this

```
 myArray.each {
        def testStr = it
        shouldFail(IllegalArgumentException) {
            println "it = " + testStr
            testObj.testMyString("$prefix $testStr", mockBuilder);
         }
    }
```

I guess "it" is not available in inner closures

Comment: It's not that it's not available, it's just a different "it".